# Project which run in PyCharm but now as EXE when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I Developped an application using python on Pycharm, it runs perfectly when I click Run. But when I compile it as exe using pyinstaller, it won't open, giving me a ModuleNotFoundError..

The error i'm getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv\main.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_controller'
[7176] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I uninstalled and installed again pyinstaller, no luck

I added `main_controller` in the `main.spec` file inside [**hiddenimports**],
also inside **[datas]**. no luck

I added the project path in the `main.spec` file inside [**pathex**] no luck

Comment: Could you provide what your project folder looks like ? `Pyinstaller` tends to be quite sensitive to relative imports, it might help to make a fresh folder with what you need and only that so as to test and debug. Also are you using some kind of virtual environment ?